# How can i make Mezzanine 4.3 work with django 3 without errors?

Tags: django, mezzanine

How to make Mezzanine 4.3 work with django 3 on AZURE without issues

l've made a mezzanine blog and i'm facing challenges deploying it in AZURE cloud. Everything goes well but, when bind the blog with Engine X it requires me to Update Django for static files (css, js, images to show). When i update django I have the worst problems. It needs me to change lots of file settings some of which i dont even understand. May someone help me if there is a way to Deploy Mezzanine 4.3 and any version of Django without such challenges. It seems building was better than deployment Now.

I will be glad to be help in simple steps possible for this to work.
Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 0):

Mezzanine doesn't run on Django 3 yet. Actually, the community is trying to make it support Django 2.2. As far as Mezzanine is concerned, you're stuck with Django 2 still. The original maintainer has stopped working on the project for a long time and the community is trying to find a way forward for the project. If I was you, I wouldn't start a new project on Mezzanine. Its future is very uncertain.